# Where's Connor?

Tags: plot-explanation, ray-donovan

Having recently seen *Ray Donovan the Movie*, I've seen what happened to most of the Donovan family with the exception of Ray's son Connor, and it's been awhile since I've watched the show- can anyone remind me where Connor has gone and what he's been up to?

Comment: I haven't seen the final season or the movie to know if anything had changed, but as per season 6, Connor had joined the military and was visited by Terry at school...